# Button color change help using Javascript, CSS, and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on how to change the color of the buttons when one is clicked and also to change the color of the button at different times. But there seems to be a problem with my code. I need an extra pair of eyes to see my problem. Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikole/jRSz6/3/). Thanks in advance.

```
<button id="start" class="colorChange" onclick="colorChange(this)" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="here" class="colorChange" onclick="colorChange(this)"data-color="orange" style="background-color: black"></button>
<button id="now" class="colorChange" onclick="colorChange(this)"data-color="yellow" style="background-color: black">

function colorChange(obj) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000000";}

 obj.style.backgroundColor=getAttribute('data-color');
    if(obj == "start"){setTimeout(changeColor, 2000)}}

function changeColor(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        var color = buttons[i].getAttribute('data-color');
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = color;}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the JavaScript error console?

Comment: I guess `if(obj == "start")` needs to be `if(obj.getAttribute("id") == "start")`

Answer (score 0):

You have a reference error here:

```
obj.style.backgroundColor=getAttribute('data-color');
```

it should be:

```
obj.style.backgroundColor=obj.getAttribute('data-color');
```

You also need to put this code before the markup (f.ex in the `<head>`): http://jsfiddle.net/jRSz6/4/